# Excel Calculating Incremental Sum / Total / Addition?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel formula that calculates incremental total based on the lot size?

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Qty is added based on the defined lot size so that each fruit is equal or above the demand.

Comment: Could you clarify how you obtained 6 and 8?

Comment: Isn't this the same as your last two questions?

Comment: 6 is because 2 lots of apple (2*3) 8 because 2 lots orange (2*4)
@TimWilliams yes this is same because I'm still trying to look for solution to this. But I broke it down into a small and more simple pieces

Comment: Where do you get the `2` from? What is a demand of `-5` and how is it linked to the problem?

Comment: @virolino For simplicity the demand is just a manual input. 2 basically means I need to order 2 lots and each lot contains 3 apples

Comment: To make things clear, you should have 2 columns: one for the lot size, and another one for demand. Should I understand that you want something like: a*b+c*d+e*f? And write the result instead of the "-5"?

Comment: All I'm trying to do is fruit qty * lot size >= demand, we have lot size and demand so need to calculate the qty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the trick

```
=-ROUNDUP($B$1/B7,0)*B7
```

Entered your data in A1

Comment: This is simple and clever way to solve, but if I have a positive demand then my fruit qty becomes negative... and qty can't be negative, maybe I should mention this

Comment: then you simply need an absolute number every time ? `=ABS(-ROUNDUP($B$1/B7,0)*B7)`